# CodeBehind TextBox Binding

Tags: wpf, code-behind

My goal was to replace `<TextBox Text={Binding TopTextContent} />` (which works as is) in the xaml view with this in the code behind:

```
  public partial class MyView: UserControl
  {
    public MyView()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      // Supposed to replace: // <TextBox Text={Binding TopTextContent} />
      InputContextMenu("Top Text", "TopTextContent");
    }

    private void InputContextMenu([NotNull] string header, [NotNull] string propName)
    {
      var textBox = new TextBox
      {
        MaxLength = 12,
        Width = 80,
        FocusVisualStyle = null
      };

      textBox.SetBinding(
        TextBox.TextProperty, 
        new Binding
        {
          Path = new PropertyPath(propName),
          Source = DataContext, // (MyView)DataContext didn't work as well
          Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        }
      );

      CodeBehindTextInputs.Items.Add(
        new MenuItem
        {
          Header = header,
          Focusable = false,
          Items = {textBox}
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Afaik it should work but it doesn't, the field does appear but the input field is empty and modifying it doesn't modify the value it is supposed to be binded to.

Snoop shows it in red:

[image: showcasing that snoop does show {Path=TopTextContent} but in red]

I'm not sure how to further debug it or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the DataContext already set when InputContextMenu is called?

Comment: @Clemens I got this in my UserControl: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type Context:MyViewModel}}`

Comment: `d:something` is for design time and doesn't work in runtime

Comment: `d:DataContext` sets the design-time DataContext only, so the result of `Source = DataContext,` is null. It is however unclear with which DataContext `Text={Binding TopTextContent}` has worked before.

Comment: @Clemens That's a good question I will try to answer, I don't have the full view on the project yet (big team). But other `TextBox`s added by the XAML show up BEFORE my "TopTextContent" TextBox and their binding work just fine, shouldn't that mean that DataContext is not null?

Comment: How should we possibly tell that, without knowing your code? However, if the DataContext is not set before the Binding is created in code behind, the Binding's Source will obviously be null. Try not to set the Source at all and thus make the Binding use the DataContext that is potentially set later.

Comment: @Clemens I provided a solution that worked for me below. You lead me to finding the problem and solution. :) (thanks)

Comment: How about not setting Source at all?

Comment: @Clemens I didn't know this was an option... It does work. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not explicitly set the Binding's Source. The Binding will automatically use the TextBox's DataContext as source object - which inherits its value from its parent view element - even when it is set later:

```
textBox.SetBinding(
    TextBox.TextProperty, 
    new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(propName),
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding it all yet but it would seem that my DataContext does get populated AFTER the constructor (so it was still null).

I solved it by resorting to the `DataContextChanged` event:

```
public SpecificInformationView()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DataContextChanged += OnDataContext;
}

private void OnDataContext(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  InputContextMenu("Top Text", "TopTextContent");
}
```